# Ruby on rails , looping through a table in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have  my application designed using Php-Mysql and I should convert it to rails. I have a table called coordinates and a search form for the same.I have two variables called latitude and longitude. the coordinates table cantains city,latitude and longitude. when the user enters the city and if it's found in the table then it should assign that  city to the matching city in the coordinates table and the latitude and longitude should be assigned to the  respective latitude and longitude in the coordinates table.
my code

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM coordinates");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        if(strtolower($location) == strtolower($row['city'])){
            $latitude = (float) $row['latitude'];
            $longitude = (float) $row['longitude'];
            break;
        }
```

This s my php code . location is entered by the user in the search button. I want the same thing t to b implemented using rails . anyone pls  help me to implement the rails code . thks  in advance`

Comment: You want us to **help** you implement or to **implement** this for you? Show your attempts.

Comment: since I am a newbie to rails I  would like anyone to help me  to implement the rails code .

Comment: sure i wil paste it here.

Comment: Can you clarify this bit of your question *it should assign that city to the matching city in the coordinates table* .. from the question it sounds like entry in the coordinates table will already have that value so no assignment should be needed?

Comment: its something like  the user is entering the city and if it is found in the coordinates table its should assign  the city attribute in d coordinates table to the entered search query and the external variables latitude and longitude  to the latitude and longitude attributes of the coordinates table of that particular object

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've created an ActiveRecord model for coordinates you can do something like:

```
coordinate = Coordinate.where(city: city_to_find).take
```

and the latitude will be in `coordinate.latitude` and the longitude in `coordinate.longitude`.

Notice that this doesn't use a loop and will run a database query to retrieve just the required record, and that you could have taken a similar approach with your PHP code.